# Response Data via URLSessionUploadTask

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, urlsession

I am writing simple handler for communication with REST API on server (currently local). Everything goes well so far with downloading and uploading data from/to server.

What I am trying to achieve now is to be able to handle JSON response returned by server after uploading data. This message is something like this:

```
{"message":"Record successfully added.","recordID":30}
```

Important is for me the **recordID**, because I need to assign it to relevant NSManagedObject. I use delegation attitude instead of completionHandler so I would be able to manage progress of the upload. Appropriate delegate class implements these protocols with all methods:

```
class ConstructoHTTPHelper:NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate, URLSessionStreamDelegate { ... }
```

Here comes the issue because as far as I create upload task with something like this:

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default 
self.session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main) //URLSession(configuration: config)
var request:URLRequest = URLRequest(url:address)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let data = // creation of data ...
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("uploadData")
do {
   try data.write(to: fileURL)
}   catch {
   // handling error
}
self.sessionUploadTask = self.session?.uploadTask(with: request, fromFile: fileURL)
self.sessionUploadTask!.resume()
```

The delegate func for handling data:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {}
```

returned by server **is never called**.
What is strange to me is that when I use completion Handler like the one below, It prints the JSON well:

```
self.sessionUploadTask = self.session?.uploadTask(with: request, from: data, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
   print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
})
```

So it looks to me that uploadTask is limited in this way. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44362939/5461400 check this @jan R.

Comment: Thanks but as  I wrote it in my post, completion handler works fine this way for me... but I need to use delegate approach instead of completionHandler because of the ability to watch the progress of session...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40503024/5461400 check here @Jan R.

Comment: Thanks, frankly this does not look like answer to my question...but thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I probably found the answer, just add this to URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveResponse:completionHandler: delegate method.

```
completionHandler(URLSession.ResponseDisposition.allow)
```

I found solution in [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653182/nsurlsession-delegate-vs-completionhandler?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 2):

try this!, get a `NSMutableData` as buffer like this globally

```
fileprivate var buffer:NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
```

and in your URLSession delegate method add,

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
  if let _ = error {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
    }else {
      // do your parsing with buffer here.
    }
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
    buffer.append(data)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it does not help. The issue is that none of the methods above (didCompleteWithError and didReceive data) are called during or after uploading...